# MongoDb Factory with spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I want to use MongoDB with Spring. 
I'm trying to inject a MongoDbFactory in my DAO main class.

I dont want to use MongoTemplate because I need to use the MongoDB-Driver

When I try to run a jUnit Test, for test my DAO class, i get an NullPointerExeption on my factory....

I think it's a problem with my injection.

**My app-config :**

```
<bean id="mongoFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <property name="port" value="27017"/>   
</bean>

<bean id="mongoDbFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="agence_voyage" />
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="dao.daoImpl.DaoImpl">
    <property name="mongoFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

**my DAO class :**

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
 private MongoDbFactory mongoFactory;
 private DB db;

 @Required
 public void setMongoFactory(MongoDbFactory myMongoFactory){
     this.mongoFactory= myMongoFactory;
 }

//TODO development mongodb://localhost
public void connect() throws UnknownHostException {
    try{
        this.db = mongoFactory.getDb("agence_voyage"); //NullPointer here
    }
    catch(DataAccessException d){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

public int getVoyageCount(String collection) {
    DBCollection col = db.getCollection(collection);
    return (int) col.count();
}
}
```

**And then my little test :**

```
public class TestDao {

@Test
public void test() {
    Dao test = new DaoImpl();
    try {
        test.connect();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        assertTrue(false);
    }
    assertTrue(test.getVoyageCount("voyage")== 1);
}

}
```

Have you got any solution ?
I'm sure it's an idiot error but I don't find it !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It doesn't seem like your test is in any way connected to the Spring context.** You actually create the object yourself instead of getting a Spring managed bean

```
Dao test = new DaoImpl();
```

Why would Spring do anything to this object?

Add these annotations to your class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "yourfile.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

and inject the `DaoImpl` bean directly.

```
@Autowired
private Dao test;
```

Then use that in your test.

Read the [chapter on unit testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) in the Spring documentation.

Comment: Ok do you know which dependencies i need to import, because i get errors on SpringJUnit4Clas... And @ContextConfiguration doesn't seems to exits.

Comment: @user2323241 They are part of `spring-test`. You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test).